# Schema editing options

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a user named `'d2mgr'` with that user login i have to Edit schema.

insert/delete table are working but schema editing is getting restriction access with error msg:

```
"Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot alter the schema 'exe', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."
```

so i added role member `'db_ddladmin'` in a stored procedure and created a new database and added a temporary table with some temporary values in it even then i am getting same restriction for editing/altering the schema please suggest me with some good answer

Comment: What exactly do you do when "editing schema"? Please, provide code.

Comment: thanks for ur reply its working and for other user named as 'd2user' i want to restrict access for schema editing for that user suggest for this one

Comment: I think @Igor was asking what command did you execute that caused the error above. Was it `ALTER SCHEMA` or something else? The permissions required for every SQL Server command are mentioned in the documentation.